# Editing the text of a mathematical annotation

Tags: r, ggplot2

Do you know why I can't edit the text of a mathematical annotation when I insert it in ggplot? For example, after I set the following axes labels:
    labs(title = "Title", y = expression("Less " %<->% " More"))
And later add the following in theme:
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13, face = "bold"))
The y axis title doesn't get bolded or larger. I also want to move the label down the y axis a bit, and I think I need vjust for that. But when I add vjust in element_text above, nothing changes. Do you know why the text doesn't get edited here? Is it because it can't deal with the arrow that "%<->%" ends up creating?

Answer (score 0):

plotmath doesn't care for bold or italics in `gpar()`

```
grid.newpage()
grid.text("test", gp=gpar(fontface=4))
grid.newpage()
grid.text(expression("test"), gp=gpar(fontface=4))
```

but there are plotmath functions to achieve the same result,

```
grid.newpage()
grid.text(expression(bolditalic("test")))
```

Comment: Thank you for addressing my question, but I'm not totally following you. Here's what I inputted in labs to edit my y axis label based on the second code block you mentioned, but this did not work:
  labs(title = "Title",
       y = grid.text(expression(bolditalic("Less " %<->% " More"))). What should I be doing differently?

Comment: `ggplot() + labs(y = expression(bolditalic("Less " %<->% " More")))`

Comment: thank you for clarifying! any easy way to change its positioning along y axis? maybe with vjust? I just don't know because it doesn't do anything when I adjust vjust in element_text() within theme